# google places api error with jquery ajax call... html_attributions

Tags: api, jquery

I'm using the new google places api with jquery/ajax.  When I run this code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.7834345,-73.9662495&radius=50&sensor=false&key=Your_API_KEY_HERE",
dataType: "jsonp",
data: {
    name: 'rogue'
},
success: function( data ) {
     console.log(data)
}
});
```

I get this error:  invalid label html_attributions [];  I think this is preventing me from seeing the output object in the console, although I can see the response coming back fine in the json tab in firebug

Comment: maybe dataType should be json, as suppose to jsonp

Comment: I don't think that can work since google and my servers are 2 different domains.... so you have to do jsonp

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the places api does not support ajax so far.

It not enough that the server responds with proper JSON. **The answering server has to support JSONP and surround the JSON answer with a callback generated by jQuery**. The response must look like that:

```
jQuery17101705844928510487_1324249734338({"data":"whatever"});
```

The hack that JSONP does, is to interpret the response as script, because the script-Tag is not affected by the Same-Origin-Policy. Without the callback you have no chance to do that in the browser.

If its not supported you have to **do the requests from your server.**.

Server-Example with PHP:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/javascript"); // avoid browser warnings
$request = new HttpRequest("http://programmingisart.com/json-data-source.php", HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$request->send();
$json_data = $request->getResponseBody();

// wrap the data as with the callback
$callback = isset($_GET["callback"]) ? $_GET["callback"] : "alert";
echo $callback."(".$json_data.");";
```

Client-Example with jQuery:

```
<div id="json-result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "jsonp-wrapper.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#json-result").html(JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**You can replace the PHP-code with any other server-platform and do the required steps.**

- HTTP-Request to a JSON source
- Wrap the JSON as with a callback-function

Comment: Could you explain what http://programmingisart.com/json-data-source.php is in the first example and what json-wrapper.php is in the second example? Where does the Google API url fit in to these code examples?