# Google Places API - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, google-places-api

I've been researching this for over an hour, and can't find a solution that works.

My js:

```
 var googleUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&language=fr&key=<MY KEY>'

  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: googleUrl,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(response)    {

          console.log(response)
       },
      error: function(response)    {
          console.log(response);
      }

  })
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509019/google-places-api-json-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token), which suggested a 'callback method' - I still can no figure out why I'm getting the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

I see it has been marked a duplicate -- but as I have already indicated, I have tried everything in that other post, and I am still unable to get the access to work, without using JSONP. Constructive feedback of how to solve the problem would be useful.

Any advice is appreciated!!

UPDATE - obviously my key in my code is not 'my key'.

Comment: Yes I'm sure that's my code.

Comment: I just tried your code, with my API key, and it worked when I changed the content type to `json`

Comment: The response is `JSON`, not `JSONP`. They are not interchangable. Change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`, *However* that then leads to a `No Access Control Header` error as the URL you're calling doesn't have CORS headers in the response. Therefore you cannot make an AJAX request to that domain. You need to do it server side instead

Comment: @legotin lol I think he just put it as `<MY KEY>` rather than publishing his API key online !! I'm sure in his code he has the real key ;)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - this shouldn't have been marked as duplicate, they are similar questions but caused by very different issues

Comment: Can I suggest that maybe you don't use `$.ajax` at all - it's old school and that's why Google is no longer supporting `jsonp`. Instead what your trying to do it easily possible with Google's nice client-side JavaScript library. Check out the docs, here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: The underlying problem is identical. The confusion is caused from the misconception that JSONP is a magical fix to missing CORS headers

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you suggest a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error is due to the fact that `googleUrl` responses with JSON, not JSONP, that you specified as `dataType` parameter.
So, just change `dataType` from `jsonp` to `json`.
You can learn more about this formats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp).

Comment: If I use JSON, the I get this error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=geocode&language=fr&key=<MY KEY>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Perhaps, you should change GET-parameter `key` from `<MY KEY>` to the real key.

Comment: Yup, that's a whole new error. 
@Legotin answered your original question, you should accept his answer

Comment: @legotin duh.  Obviously I have a key in my code. I'm not posting my key in this public forum.  This is not the issue, nor does the error indicate that is the issue.

Comment: @legotin - why do you keep mentioning `<MY KEY>` (first in a comment below the question, and now here)? This is *exactly* how someone should represent their key, vs actual key (which happens *all* the time).

Comment: This is a good solution, thank you!