# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in angularJS and Web API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I don't know what is the problem in my code :

**My Factory Code**

```
AddDealApp.factory('AddDealService', ['$http', function ($http) {

    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    var fac = {};

    fac.GetPlaces = function (searchtext) {
        searchtext = searchtext.replace(" ", "+");
        var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=' + searchtext + '&key=AIzaSyD-s3kxWqrVnBUkxCzkGb8vRy1dld3RSz4';

        var req = {
            method: 'get',
            url: url
        }

        var result = $http(req)
        return result
    }

    return fac;
}])
```

**Configuration Code :**

```
AddDealApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}
]);
```

**In My Web.config File :**

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

I did every thing to get the cross domain data , but it is still showing the same error.

If I request **JSONP**,then data is coming, but the response recieved from the url is always in xml format.

**UPDATE :**
Now I am trying to get the same thing with JSONP. Data is recieving, But it still showing error.
Plunkr :
https://plnkr.co/edit/2BILJy2wsBrWlMrgMurZ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular $http always expects JSON data and not xml.

If you change your url to json then you will get json responses from google instead of xml:

```
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=' + searchtext + '&key=AIzaSyD-s3kxWqrVnBUkxCzkGb8vRy1dld3RSz4';
```

But according to Google the preferred method is to use their JS libraries.

I use this angular library and it works great: https://github.com/kuhnza/angular-google-places-autocomplete

Here's my input:

```
<input class="form-control form-group-sm" type="text"
           id="ga_search"
           g-places-autocomplete options="autocompleteOptions"
           ng-model="ga_search"/>
```

And here's my controller function

```
$scope.ga_search = "";
                var watch = $scope.$watch('ga_search.address_components', function () {
                    //console.log("Update address");
                    if (typeof($scope.ga_search.address_components) != "undefined") {
                        $scope.propdata.street_number = "";
                        $scope.propdata.street = "";
                        $scope.propdata.suburb_text = "";
                        $scope.propdata.town_text = "";
                        $scope.propdata.region_text = "";
                        $scope.propdata.country_text = "";
                        $scope.propdata.post_code = "";
                        angular.forEach($scope.ga_search.address_components, function (val, key) {
                            //console.log(val);
                            switch (val.types[0]) {
                                case "street_number" :
                                    $scope.propdata.street_number = val.long_name;
                                    break;
                                case "route" :
                                    $scope.propdata.street = val.long_name;
                                    break;
                                case "sublocality_level_1" :
                                    $scope.propdata.suburb_text = val.long_name;
                                    break;
                                case "administrative_area_level_2" :
                                    $scope.propdata.town_text = val.long_name;
                                    break;
                                case "administrative_area_level_1" :
                                    $scope.propdata.province_text = val.long_name;
                                    break;
                                case "country" :
                                    $scope.propdata.country_text = val.long_name;
                                    break;
                                case "postal_code" :
                                    $scope.propdata.post_code = val.long_name;
                                    break;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: ya I change to json. But now It is showing unexpected token after recieving JSON data.

Comment: can you check in Chrome console right-click log XHR and then click on the query and post us the response you getting from the server as well as all the headers. Could you comment the removal of the X-Requested-With header as well

Comment: The invalid JSON token definitely comes from Google's api, according to this thread you need to wrap the request in PHP or any Server-side processing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080050/google-places-api-error-with-jquery-ajax-call-html-attributions

Comment: I have a similar Address search function in my app and mine works fine, but not via $http, you have to add the Google api javascript library into your project and use the new google.maps.places object. As per this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library